# ' No account for team 'LXxxxxxxx' ' build error on Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, xcode-project

I am cloning a Xcode project from github and is my first experience with Xcode projects. 
I tried simulating on Mac for a device (say iphone SE) and it works fine. However, when I connect a iphone and try to build the project on the target device as my iphone, it gives this error.

Code Signing Error : `No account for team "LXxxxxxxx". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.`

I have signed into my Apple ID under accounts tab in preferences. Is there is something wrong with account ? or How do I detach from this 'team account' ?

Could you please provide me some instructions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Add your team account to Xcode**

Add your team account in Accounts preference pane in Xcode.

**Step 2: Assign the target to a team**

In the target preferences, enable "Automatic manage signing" then assign the target to your team.

Comment: I not working on a team account. I am just trying out a open source project found on github. So the team should be set to "personal team" right ?

Answer (score 1):

when you are building your project into device you have to be logged in team account with your Apple Developer Id. After this if not works then change Bundle ID of your project for example if your bundle id is - `com.Demo.App` then change it to `com.Demo.App123`

Answer (score 0):

In my case 
before do that apply credentials to my mac it means double click